# Can't find the portable template for xamarin native in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I can't find a portable template for Xamarin Native in Visual Studio 2017. As you can see in the screenshot

[image]

But I want to make the Xamarin. Android and Xamarin.iOS as a cross-platform but I'm not getting the portable template for that. But I have seen in some places there are templates where we can get a portable file for Native Xamarin as well. You can see the screenshot below

[image]

Any suggestion how can I get the portable file for native Xamarin. The main reason why I need the portable file is that I wanted to do code sharing between Xamarin.android and Xamarin.iOS.

Comment: Where you seen portable templates those are old projects, I think.

Comment: @user3452  Are you looking for a Xamarin.iOS project template?

Comment: @hashimks No, I'm not looking for the Xamarin.iOS project template that we have in VS 2017 no doubt I'm looking for a template similar to portable and .net shared which is available for Xamarin forms but not for Xamarin native.

Comment: Are you referring to the cross platform project template? Not the Android and iOS project... Am I right?

Comment: Cross-platform project template for native Xamarin.

Comment: There is no such a thing as Xamarin Native. You completely miss-understand the concept of Xamarin. You can build applications using 2 approaches. Xamarin Forms, which allows you to create crossplatform app where both of the platforms share majority of code(like ui for example) and Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android where you write 2 separate applications and you code natively except in C#.

Comment: First of all, as of April 2018 or something Portable class libraries for Xamarin have been deprecated and the way to do it now is using the `.Net standard` project in place of it and hence from Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5  PCL's are just not available, What I would suggest you did instead though is just add normal Xamarin forms.`Net Standard` project to your application and then add them to where you want the reference to.

Comment: @G.hakim so if I create Xamarin forms .NET standard project I can still do the Xamarin native functionality in that. That is creating designs in storyboard and setting the control to view controller.?

Comment: Is it possible to do code sharing in xamarin native just as xamarin forms?

Comment: @user3452 `Xamarin.iOS` and `Xamarin.Android` is independent. Project of `Xamarin.iOS` can't  run in an  `Android` System. There is no meaning to do code sharing in `xamarin.native`. The code in `Xamarin.iOS` and `Xamarin.Android` is totally different.

Comment: @user3452 See I think you have a little confusion, How it basically works is Xamarin.iOS uses the native iOS objective c behaviour having storyboards and view controllers, Xamarin.Android uses the native java behaviour using xmls, activities, fragments. And Xamarin Forms is the cross-platform dev tool that works on both at the same time. Now if you add a PCL or.NetStandard to your Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS projects you can use them to write common code for eg: Bussiness layers, services etc but you cannot reference them to each other like and Android cannot reference ios and vice versa

Comment: But on the other hand you can have a common service layer using a .Net Standard library while using Xamarin.Android/iOS which can use the same models(almost all the time) and services.

Comment: Thanks @G.hakim you explained me really well.

Comment: Sure no problem if that is satisfactory to you i can add it as an answer

Comment: Yeah sure @G.hakim.

Comment: @user3452 Done you can have a look now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See I think you have a little confusion, How it basically works is `Xamarin.iOS` uses the native iOS `objective-c` behaviour having storyboards and view controllers, `Xamarin.Android` uses the native java behaviour using xmls, activities, fragments. And `Xamarin.Forms` is a cross-platform dev tool that works on both at the same time using XAML with all three working in a C# code-behind environment.

Now if you add a PCL or.NetStandard to your Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS projects you can use them to write common code for eg: Business layers, services etc but you cannot reference them to each other like an `Android`project cannot reference `iOS` and vice versa.

But on the other hand, you can have a common service layer using a `.Net Standard` library while using `Xamarin.Android/iOS` which can use the same models(almost all the time) and services.

Note that `Xamarin-Forms` .Net standard and PCL's are the same, But until and unless you add the `Xamarin.Forms`package and do the necessary changes that are required for forms your application will pretty much be a Xamarin.Android/Xamarin.iOS project, with a .Net standard or a PCL as a project reference.

Also, note that PCL's are deprecated and hence it is recommended by xamarin that you use .Net standard libraries,

Curious about the difference between them? [check this out](https://stackify.com/net-standard-explained/)

For a better understanding of what PCL and .Net standard is you can check the below links:

PCL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/pcl?tabs=windows

.Net Standard : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard